# Al hacer scroll en el Recycler View se cambian de posición las urls

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android y alguno de los elementos tienen url, pero al hacer scroll en el recycler view se me mueven las urls y se me ponen en los elementos que no deberían tener.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Alertas alerta = mAndroidList.get(position);

    if(mRadio) {
        holder.mTvDistrito.setText(alerta.getDistrito());
    }
    holder.mTvCategoria.setText(alerta.getCategoria());
    holder.mTvFecha.setText(alerta.getFecha());
    holder.mTvAlerta.setText(alerta.getAlertas());
    if(alerta.getUrl() != null) {

        holder.mTvAlerta.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4081"));
        holder.mTvAlerta.setPaintFlags(holder.mTvAlerta.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

        enlace = alerta.getUrl();

        holder.mTvAlerta.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(enlace);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
```

El problema es que al principio todos aparece bien y las url van bien pero al hacer scroll las url se ponen en otros lados.

Answer (score 2):

Al hacer `Scroll` en un [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView), las vistas se reciclan (dependendo del `itemViewCacheSize` definido).

El [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView), define el siguiente ciclo para reciclar sus vistas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Cuando una vista se desplaza fuera de la pantalla y ya no se muestra, se
>   convierte en una vista de desecho (**Scrap View**).
>
> La vista de desecho (**Scrap View**) se coloca en un grupo y se
>   convierte en una vista de reciclaje (**Recycle View**). Este conjunto
>   es un caché de vistas que **muestra el mismo tipo de datos**.
>
> Cuando se muestra un nuevo elemento, se toma una vista del grupo de
>   reciclaje para su reutilización. Debido a que el adaptador debe volver
>   a unir esta vista antes de mostrarse, se denomina vista sucia (**Dirty
>   View**).
>
> La vista sucia (**Dirty View**) se recicla: **el adaptador ubica los
>   datos para el siguiente elemento que se va a mostrar y copia estos
>   datos** en las vistas de este artículo. Las referencias de estas
>   vistas se obtienen del titular de la vista asociado con la vista
>   reciclada.
>
> La vista reciclada se agrega a la lista de elementos en el
>   [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) que están a punto de aparecer en la pantalla.
>
> La vista reciclada aparece en la pantalla mientras el usuario desplaza
>   el [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) al siguiente elemento de la lista. Mientras
>   tanto, otra vista se desplaza fuera de la vista y se recicla de
>   acuerdo con los pasos anteriores.

En pocas palabras, el `RecyclerView` amontona las vistas que desaparecen y toma esas vistas para formar las que van apareciendo nuevas, por lo que las vistas que tengan propiedades alteradas, debes volverla a su estado original, ya que si no lo haces asi, las vistas que se crearan con base a la reciclada (las que no estan visibles), se les asignara propiedades que quizás no quieres, digase, visibility, backgrounds, sizes, animaciones, etc...

Dicho esto, puedes estar cometiendo un error importante:

### **No defines el caso de ruptura o reestablecimiento de la vista.**

Segun veo tu código, siempre estas asignando una propiedad a un elemento y no estas removiéndola, por ende, al hacer `Scroll`, siempre se mostrara una vista reciclada (que tiene o puede tener propiedades de quien la creo).

La solucion aqui, es definir todos los casos posibles con una condicion, si quieres que tome cada caso como quieras. Por ejemplo, si quieres que una vista cambie de color, dependiendo de la posicion, debes hacer todos los casos y el caso de ruptura, por ejemplo:

```
if(position == 1)
      // Si la posicion es 1, debe ser rojo
else if(position == 2)
     // Si la posicion es dos, debe ser azul
else
    // todos los demas deben ser negros, este es el caso de ruptura o reestablecimiento
```

Si no defines un caso de ruptura, notaras que al hacer scroll puede ser que se vea rojo o azul donde no quieres, porque la vista que se creo, se ha recreado con una vista reciclada, que a lo mejor era roja o azul.

En tu caso deberías hacer lo siguiente para llegar a **la solución**:

```
if(alerta.getUrl() != null) {
       // Tu codigo tal como esta
    }
else
   // Volver mTvAlerta a su color original y remover el onClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado con la respuesta de @Andrespengineer.
Como recicla las vistas que no se ven, las vistas nuevas que va a mostrar las crea con las recicladas y si no se le hace cambio a dichas vistas estás quedarán con información antigua.
En mi caso tenia unas vistas con video e imágenes entonces en las vistas que no tenían video se colocaba visibilidad "gone" y las que si tenía simplemente se dejaba, lo que pasaba era que solo tenia la validación si tenia video, y como la vista reciclada si lo tenia entonces me lo mostraba, la solución fue simple, agregar un "else" a la validacion que ya tenía para colocar visibilidad "gone" al video.

```
if(productosDisplayVO.getVideoProducto() != null && productosDisplayVO.getVideoProducto() != ""){
        
        _cargarVideo(productosDisplayVO, holder);

    }else{
        
        holder.thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Muchísimas Gracias, me sirvió de mucho, llevaba como 3 días intentando cosas e investigando el por qué.

Comment: quisiera tu ayuda, hice lo mismo pero en un onBinViewHolder y lo tengo enlazado con position, pero al darle scroll, los colores se mueven completamente, pasa lo que comentas pero nose como ponerle la condicion, esta es mi condicon -> if (Integer.parseInt(listplpro.get(position).getXingresado()) == 0) {
                //holder.xcantart.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006064"));
                holder.xcantart.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }