# ¿Por qué al colocarle backgroundColor a un cardview del recyclerview se pintan otros cardview que no corresponden?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Mi idea es que al presionar el elemento se coloque un color de fondo diferente.

**Clase Adaptador**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VariablesAdaptador extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<VariablesAdaptador.VariablesViewHolder>{

ArrayList<VariablesPOJO> variables;
Activity activty;


public VariablesAdaptador(ArrayList<VariablesPOJO> variables, Activity activity){
    this.variables = variables;
    this.activty = activity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public VariablesAdaptador.VariablesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_variables,parent,false);
    return new VariablesViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final VariablesAdaptador.VariablesViewHolder vaiablesViewHolder, final int position) {
    final VariablesPOJO variable = variables.get(position);
    vaiablesViewHolder.texto_variables.setText(variable.getVariable());

    vaiablesViewHolder.texto_variables.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vaiablesViewHolder.cardView_variables.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            //variables.remove(position);
            notifyItemChanged(position, variables.size());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Intent intent = new Intent(activty, detalle_variable.class);
            intent.putExtra("variable",variable.getVariable());
            activty.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return variables.size();
}

public static class VariablesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView texto_variables;
    private CardView cardView_variables;

    public VariablesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView_variables = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_variables);
        texto_variables = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_variables);
    }
}
```

}

**CardView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cardview_variables"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation="20dp"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
card_view:contentPadding="11dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="11dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_cardview"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_variables"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/nombre_variable"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: El problema es que no estas definiendo el caso de reestablecer la vista. [Mira esta respuesta que hice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166382/38154) para que entiendas el funcionamiento del RecyclerView y dicho sea de paso, resuelvas tu problema. En tu caso particular, debes establecer una propiedad booleana para tu item y evaluar: `if(item.isSelected())` pintalo del color que quieras, `else` pintalo del color normal. O puedes utilizar la propiedad setSelected del ItemView del holder.

Answer (score 0):

Para pintar un **CardView** se usa **setCardBackgroundColor(int color);**.

Este es un método público que actualiza el color de fondo del CardView. Si utilizas el **setBackgroundColor** puede que funcione pero, cuando lo pinte no tomará en cuenta los bordes que le has agregado y te lo rellenará todo sin esos radios. Lo mejor es usar el método que proporciona el componente.

Para tu problema quedaría entonces:

```
vaiablesViewHolder.cardView_variables.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Eso debería ser suficiente para cambiar el color del cardview. Saludos.