# Obtener posición de los items en un RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Buen día. Lo que pretendo es obtener la posición de los items de un `RecyclerView` pero no con un click sino mientras se desliza la lista de items, que en mi caso es una lista de imágenes.

Lo que quiero lograr es habilitar y deshabilitar un par de imágenes que tengo encimadas.

Entiendo que mi código debe ser algo así:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterGaleryReserve.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ItemGalery item = items.get(position);

    Fuente fuente = new Fuente();
    Typeface typefaceSuperReg = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), fuente.getFuenteSuperRegular());
    holder.textView.setTypeface(typefaceSuperReg);

    holder.textView.setText(item.getText1());

    switch (item.getId()){
        case "0":
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img15);
            break;
        case "1":
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img17);
            break;
        case "2":
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img16);
            break;
    }

    holder.contend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String posision;
            posision = item.getId();
            Toast.makeText(context, posision, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(posision.equals("0")){
                holder.imageViewBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imageViewNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if(posision.equals("2")){
                holder.imageViewBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageViewNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                holder.imageViewBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imageViewNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Pero como repito **no quiero que funcione con un click** (como funciona actualmente) si no tal vez con algún listener o mientras se desliza para la visualización de las imágenes. Espero haberme hecho entender y que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: y metiendo por ejemplo

`holder.imageViewBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
                `holder.imageViewNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
dentro del `switch (item.getId())`
en el case que desees?

Comment: te refieres a meter la visibilidad dentro del Switch?

Comment: si, mientras se van creando, ir seteando las imagenes

Comment: Te funciono la solución propuesta?, si es así, no olvides aceptar la respuesta para que la pregunta no quede abierta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El `onBindViewHolder` ya recibe un parámetro `position` que es la posición del item mientras deslizas la pantalla. Simplemente elimina el `onClick` y lo del `item.getId()`. Te debe quedar algo así:

. . .

```
switch (position){
    case 0:
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img15);
        break;
    case 1:
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img17);
        break;
    case 2:
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img16);
        break;
    }

if(posision == 0)){
    holder.imageViewBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.imageViewNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
 else if(posision == 2){
    holder.imageViewBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.imageViewNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else{
    holder.imageViewBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.imageViewNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
```

Ahora bien, debes tener en cuenta que estas cargando imágenes según la posición, y el funcionamiento del `RecyclerView`, luego de que comience a reciclar las vistas, cargara dichas vistas con propiedades de otras "Recicla" y eso hará que si no haces un caso de re-establecimiento de la vista, esta al hacer scroll rápidamente, te aparezca una que otra imagen en una posición que no quieres.

Puedes revisar [Esta Respuesta y Explicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166382/38154) que hice a una pregunta para entender el funcionamiento del `RecyclerView`. Con esto me refiero a que debes poner un caso `default` en tu `switch` que carga la imagen, limpiando el `ImageView`, **asignándole un background null o el que tiene por defecto**.

Para tu ejemplo, tu `switch` deberia quedar asi:

```
switch (position){
    case 0:
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img15);
        break;
    case 1:
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img17);
        break;
    case 2:
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img16);
        break;
    default:
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        break;
    }
```