# RecyclerView: Al borrar se duplica el item de abajo

Tags: android, recyclerview, component, android-recyclerview

Estoy teniendo un problema hace tiempo, busque por todos lados y siempre dan la misma solucion pero a mi no me funciona

Tengo un recycler view que al hacer swipe horizontal elimino el item de los datos. el item se elimina correctamente, los datos estan correctos, pero el recycler view replica mal los datos...

Lo que hace es duplicarme el dato que se encuentra justo debajo de el, no puedo encontrarle solucion a esto, no se si la libreria tiene un bug (libreria nativa)

Dejo aca un poco de datos

DEPENDENCIAS:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Adapter del RV:

```
 class AdapterRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecycler.ViewHolderContactos> {
    ArrayList<c_Contactos> mListaContactos;

    AdapterRecycler(ArrayList<c_Contactos> mListaContactos) {
        this.mListaContactos = mListaContactos;
    }

    void eliminarItem(int index) {
        mListaContactos.remove(index);
        // adapterContactos = new AdapterRecycler(mListaContactos);
        // recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterContactos);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
        // notifyDataSetChanged();
           /* adapterContactos.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            adapterContactos.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,adapterContactos.mListaContactos.size());
           adapterContactos.mListaContactos.remove(position);
            recyclerView.removeViewAt(position);
            adapterContactos.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapterContactos.notifyItemRemoved(position);*/
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterRecycler.ViewHolderContactos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolderContactos(new cc_Contactos(getApplicationContext(), mListaContactos.get(i), (i % 2 == 0)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterRecycler.ViewHolderContactos holder, int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mListaContactos.get(position).hashCode();
        // return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListaContactos.size();
    }

    class ViewHolderContactos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ViewHolderContactos(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

    }
}
```

Revisen el metodo ELIMINAR, ahi deje comentado todas las cosas que intente y ninguna funciono, y ahora subo un video de lo que pasa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta deshabilitar temporalmente o remover el `override` de `getItemId` de tu `Adapter`.  El `itemId` depende de los valores de tu lista en, específicamente ese `position`. Si tu lista cambia en esa posición, es decir, que el elemento que estaba ahi en esa posicion, ya no existe en especifico y luego notificas directamente al `Adapter`, para reflejar un cambio, el adaptador llamará al método `getItemId(int position)` de cada elemento y actualizará solo aquellos elementos cuyo id haya cambiado. En este caso, te cambiara los items que sigan a partir de esa posicion, porque estas removiendo.

Comment: Estas utilizando Cursores de dases de datos locales, como SQLite? y ese es todo el codigo?, porque si en el onBindViewHolder, tienes codigo, puede que ahi este el problema. Ya que puede que no estes estableciendo un caso de Ruptura. Entonces se descartaria lo del `getItemId`. Si tienes codigo en el `onBindViewHolder`, favor compartirlo editando tu pregunta para mostrarte la solucion.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Como podria remover el override si es necesario?, voy a ver de buscarle la vuelta a lo que me estas comentando y te confirmo que pude hacer.

No estoy usando cursores de una BD, solo agrego contactos a una lista y los utilizo de ahi, El adapter del RV esta completo, no falta ningun metodo ni esta tocado

Comment: No se como etiquetarte, pero sabes que no se esta ejecutando el metodo getItemId en ningun momento?, ni cuando se inicializa el adapter, ni cuando elimino un elemento

Comment: Si no sabes cómo instanciar las vistas fíjate en el `onBindViewHolder` y la clase `ViewHolder` de [ESTE EJEMPLO](https://gist.github.com/alvareztech/85ecf2a28424f6376c583466c5446ff7#file-personasadapter-java). Se me hace extraño de todas formas tú `RecyclerView`, porque no se como agregas las imágenes y el Texto a cada vista, si no tienes nada en el `onBindViewHolder`. Recuerda que a las vistas debes asignarles el texto, imagen, etc.. correspondiente al item.

Comment: No lo puedo creer!, funcionooooooo, muchisimas gracias, pone lo que  me comentaste como respuesta asi la puedo votar y seleccionar como correcta.
Las vistas y los textos se agregan por que en el onCreateViewHolder, en ves inflar un layout, estaba pasando un componente que se encargaba de inflar la vista y de cargarle los datos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que las vistas se están quedando en el estado de **DirtyView**.

> Cuando se muestra un nuevo elemento o se notifica un cambio al adaptador, se toma una vista del grupo de
> reciclaje para su reutilización. Debido a que el adaptador debe volver
> a unir esta vista antes de mostrarse, se denomina vista sucia (Dirty
> View).
>
> La vista sucia (**DirtyView**) se recicla: el adaptador ubica los datos
> para el siguiente elemento que se va a mostrar y copia estos datos en
> las vistas de este artículo. Las referencias de estas vistas se
> obtienen del titular de la vista asociado con la vista reciclada.

Puedes ver mas detalles en [Esta Respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166382/38154) donde explico un poco mas el RecyclerView y el problema de duplicar los datos.

### Solución:

---

**1.** Instancia las vistas de tu layout en la clase `ViewHolderContactos`.

**2.** En el `onBindViewHolder` necesitas modificar todas las vistas para asignarle sus propiedades. Pero por que?, porque cada vez que un elemento cambia, el bind se encarga de asegurarse que sus propiedades sean las correctas y el **DirtyView** o vista sucia, puede reestablecerse con su debido valor en la lista.

Un ejemplo de como instanciar las vistas y asignarle su valor correspondiente:

. . .

```
// Esta es la clase ViewHolder, el layout item inflado por viewType
public static class ViewHolderContactos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView;
        EditText editText;
        Button button;

        public ViewHolderContactos(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            button = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        }
```

. . .

Entonces en el `onBindViewHolder`, es donde vas a asignar las propiedades o alteraciones de la vista:

. . .

```
    // Esta clase es la que se llamara cada vez que notifiques un cambio
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterRecycler.ViewHolderContactos holder, int position) {
       Datos item = items.get(position);
       holder.textView.setText(item.nombre);
       holder.editText.setText(item.apellido);
       holder.button.setText(item.telefono);
    }
```

. . .

Entonces asi, cada vez que notifiques un cambio, se llamara `onBindViewHolder` donde se le hara set nuevamente de los datos que pertenecen al item, limpiando el **DirtyView**.

Comment: Esto es lo que necesitaba, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas actualizar el rango de items des del item eliminado al final.

```
void eliminarItem(int index) {
    mListaContactos.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(index, mListaContactos.size());
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, probe tu metodo, pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, nunca le encontre la vuelta al RV, es como si no actualizara bien los datos, lo unico que me funciono es volver a setearle el adapter al RV, pero eso causa un parpadeo en la pantalla

Comment: En el `onBindViewHolder` no actualizas las vistas?

Comment: Esta vacio ese metodo, que deberia hacer ahi?, capaz es la solucion :O