# Android Studio / ¿Por que desaparecen mis vistas en recycler view?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy sufriendo este error **tan particular** el cual hace que al deslizar las vistas de mi recycler view, estas **desaparezcan**. Probando con el código xml me di cuenta de que el único responsable de esto es el "txt_separador" el cual verán adjuntado en el código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_resultados"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_foto_item_row_recycler_resultados"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_nombre_item_row_recycler_resultados"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Jorge Hernandez"
            android:textColor="#1B1B1B"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_descripcion_item_row_recycler_resultados"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Ver descripción"
            android:textColor="#5C7474"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_nombre_item_row_recycler_resultados" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_separador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linear_calificacion"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_calificacion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_calificacion_item_row_recycler_resultados"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:textColor="#006064"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Este **"txt_separador"** lo utilizo **CADA VEZ** que diseño vistas para un recycler view. El problema es que solo en este recycler me genera la falla que provoca la desaparición de las vistas y realmente no entiendo por qué.

**Aclaración:** "txt_separador" lo utilizo para que se mantenga la distancia entre el **constraint layout que contiene el nombre y la descripción** y el **linear que contiene el txt_calificacion**

**EXTRA: Adjunto el código xml de otra vista de otro recycler view en el cual también uso el "txt_separador" pero en este si funciona**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraint_recycler_materias_profesor"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Televisor HD"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_precio_numero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="200 ARS"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_precio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Precio"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_precio_numero"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_separador"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="74dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Realmente agradecería un montón su ayuda para poder seguir avanzando con mi proyecto. **Agradezco su lectura**

Comment: El error parece más del Adapter, comparte el código que tienes para tu adaptador. Si quieres separar vistas o agregar alguna decoración, debes utilizar `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` en vez de utilizar vistas. Esto te ayuda a prevenir problemas de performance. Comparte el código de tu Adapter para darte la solución.

Comment: Es que son 320 líneas de código las de mi adapter. Creo que se haría muy extenso esto. Para dividir una vista de la otra uso DividerItemDecoration pero con división me refiero a una separación entre el constraint layout con nombre y descripción y el txt calificacion.

Comment: Tu problema probablemente este en tu `onBindViewHolder`. Tienes alguna condición para ocultar o visualizar alguna vista. [Revisa esta respuesta que hice hace un tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166062/al-hacer-scroll-en-el-recycler-view-se-cambian-de-posici%c3%b3n-las-urls/166382#166382) para que entiendas como funciona el `RecyclerView` y la posible causa de los errores al hacer Scroll que se producen. Si te sirve déjame un voto, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la información y por contestar de nuevo Andres. La info. que me pasaste es muy valiosa para mi!