# Switch Android se selecciona 2 veces

Tags: android, android-layout

Buen día, les comento el siguiente problema con una app que estoy desarrollando quizá pueda ayudarme. el problema consiste en que tengo una vista donde cargo datos en un recyclerview, dentro del item existe un componente Switch. todo carga perfectamente pero el problema es que al checkear un item resulta que se checkean 2 items.

ya verifique con Log que el item extra checkeado no se muestra en el Log. Solo se muestra el item que si reconozco haber checkeado. quisiera saber si ya alguien ha tenido ese problema, a que se debe y como se podría solucionar?

codigo item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#2905A1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#E4E3E3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/producto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#026FB8"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/productoSwitch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Switch"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <!--android:trackTint="@drawable/animtrackswitch"
                    android:thumbTint="@drawable/animswitch"-->

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

codigo Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recycler=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.Recyler);


    try {
        TareaWSProducto producto = new TareaWSProducto();
        producto.execute();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Resultado create", e.getMessage()+" | "+e.getCause());
    }

    limpiarSwitch();



}
private void loadProducto() {

        ArrayList<Productos> listaDatos = (ArrayList<Productos>) jsonResult_list;

        List items = new ArrayList();
        for(int x=0;x<listaDatos.size();x++) {
                items.add(new Producto(listaDatos.get(x).getProducto()));

        }
        // Obtener el Recycler
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Usar un administrador para LinearLayout
        lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity.this);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);
        // Crear un nuevo adaptador
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(items);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

codigo CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private List<Productos> items;

public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public SwitchCompat producto;
    public CustomViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        producto = (SwitchCompat) v.findViewById(R.id.producto);
    }
}
public CustomAdapter(List<Productos> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
@Override
public CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    context=viewGroup.getContext();
    return new CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    viewHolder.producto.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getDesProducto()));


    viewHolder.producto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Item select : "+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Item deSelect : "+i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                viewHolder.cursoPA.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega tu código , es importante, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: ya agregue código, espero aquí me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que todo, [mira esta respuesta que hice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166382/38154) para que entiendas el funcionamiento del `RecyclerView` y los posibles errores de duplicidad de propiedades y vistas haciendo *scroll*.

Tu problema está en el reciclado de las vistas y hay varias formas de obtener el resultado que quieres. 
_

### No recomendado:

**• Desactivar el reciclado de vistas:** esta opción no es muy óptima porque básicamente desactiva la naturaleza por defecto del RecyclerView que es reciclar las vistas para lograr mejor Performance.

`setIsRecyclabe(false);` en la clase del ViewHolder.

**• Hacer set de la propiedad para volverla a su estado original sobre escribiendo el método que recicla las vistas:**

```
@Override 
public void onViewRecycled(CustomViewHolder holder) { 
  holder.producto.setChecked(false); // reestablecer el estado de la vista
  super.onViewRecycled(holder); 
}
```

---

### Opción recomendada:

Debes crear una propiedad en el item para que ella sea quien altere el estado de la vista, así te aseguras que todas las vistas se restablezcan con sus respectivos ítems.

En tu item:

```
private boolean checked;

public void setChecked(boolean checked){
      this.checked = checked;
}

public boolean getChecked() {
      return this.checked;
}
```

Tendrías algo como esto en tu `onBindViewHolder`:

```
viewHolder.producto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { 
          items.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())
          .setChecked(isChecked); 

}
```

Una vez asignada la propiedad, en cualquier parte del `onBindViewHolder` debes evaluar la condición y asignar la propiedad al `View`.

```
viewHolder.producto.setChecked(ítems.get(i).getChecked());
```

Cuando tienes una subclase, o estás en un contexto fuera del `onBindViewHolder` se utiliza `getAdapterPosition()` de la clase `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, para poder obtener la posición real de la vista. Las posiciones cambian, sobretodo cuando el Adaptador sufre notificaciones de cambios y reciclado, por lo que en algún momento te devuelve posiciónes inválidas mientras se ejecutan dichos cambios.

Happy coding!

Comment: genial si funcionó, una ultima pregunta en caso de querer que no cambie en estado si selecciono un item con los mismos datos ya seleccionados anteriormente como sería?

Comment: Si te refieres a que siempre se quede seleccionado el item, debes hacer un if evaluando: `if(items.get(getAdapterPosition()).getChecked()) return; `  en el listener del switch, es decir, si el item ya está seleccionado retorna en vez de asignarle la propiedad. Si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada con el icono √ check y dejarme un voto. Saludos.