# RecyclerView no cambia fondo del elemento pulsado

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

tengo una actvity que implementa un RecycleView. Al principio tenía las clases *RecyclerViewAdapters* y *RecyclerViewHolders* en otros archivos a parte, pero mi problema es que tengo un obejto (miPlan) de una clase personalizada (Plan) en la activty que tiene unos variables que se deben de poner a al valor 1 con fondo de color amarillo y letra blanca cuando se pulsen las veces impares, y a valor 0 fondo de color blanco y letra amarilla cuando se pulsen las pares (es decir, marcar desmarcar).

Decidí meter la clase del apater y del holder en el archivo java de la activity para que el holder a la vez que cambiaba lo colores de fondo y letra cambiase el valor de la variable del objeto pero no me funciona.

No sé si hay algún método que se pueda implementar en la clase holder para que si dejo las clases del holder y del adapter fuera de la clase de la activty el holder se pueda comunicar con la activty para que sea esta la que cambie la variable de la clase personalizada o que sentencia tengo mal en la clase de la activity en la que están el adapter y el holder incluidos.

Aquí dejo el código de la clase de la activity que tiene las clases del holder y del adapter por si véis el fallo (**que es que no cambia los colores del puslado, sino sólo del último elemento**)

```
public class NueMatInvernales extends Activity {

private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
private Plan miPlan;


public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
public RelativeLayout fondo;
public int pulsado=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_ava_mat);

    miPlan = new Plan();
    miPlan = (Plan)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miPlan");

    setTitle(null);

    ImageButton siguiente = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

    siguiente.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent passIntent = new Intent();

            passIntent.setClass(NueMatInvernales.this, NuevoAvaInf.class);
            startActivity(passIntent);
        }
    });


    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(NueMatInvernales.this, 5);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NueMatInvernales.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Pala", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Martillo", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Casco", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Paleta", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Espuerta", R.drawable.icon));  
 
    return allItems;


}

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {
    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

}

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
        fondo = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fondo_item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (pulsado == 0) {
            pulsado = 1;
            fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
            countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            if (getAdapterPosition()==0) {
                miPlan.setHodratacion(1);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Hidratación = " + miPlan.getHidratacion(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            pulsado = 0;
            fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));

            if (getAdapterPosition()==0)
                miPlan.setHodratacion(0);
        }

    }
 }
}
```

y aquí os dejo la clase del holder y de la activty por separado por si hubiese algún **metodo para comunicar el holder con la activty**

***Clase de la activity***

```
public class NueMatInvernales extends Activity {

private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
private Plan miPlan;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_ava_mat);

    miPlan = new Plan();
    miPlan = (Plan)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miPlan");

    setTitle(null);

    ImageButton siguiente = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

    siguiente.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent passIntent = new Intent();

            passIntent.setClass(NueMatInvernales.this, NuevoAvaInf.class);
            startActivity(passIntent);
        }
    });


    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(NueMatInvernales.this, 5);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NueMatInvernales.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Pala", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Martillo", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Casco", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Paleta", R.drawable.icon));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Espuerta", R.drawable.icon));  
 
    return allItems;
}
}
```

***Clase del Holder***

public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

```
public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
public RelativeLayout fondo;
public int pulsado=0;

public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
    fondo = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fondo_item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (pulsado==0) {
        pulsado=1;
        fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
        countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
    else
    {
        pulsado=0;
        fondo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        countryName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffbe00"));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hcaer no se te entiende muy bien comunicacion con el activity simplemente pasalo al crear al adapter, que sea una weak reference ,  ahora para que se actualize un cambio en una celda del recyclerview, tienes que actualizar el item en su index que le corresponde y notificar al adapter que se cambio tal index para q lo redibuje.

Comment: [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166382/38154) para que entiendas el funcionamiento del `RecyclerView`. Lo que pasa es que tu vista se queda en estado sucio. Todas las modificaciones de una vista deben ser expuestas en el `onBindViewHolder`  que va a reestablecer las vistas recicladas. Tienes que crear una propiedad en el item, algo como `isClicked` booleano y volverlo `true` cuando hagas click sobre ese elemento. Luego hacer `notifyItemChanged` de ese ítem en tu adaptador. En tu onBindViewHolder pones la condición para asignar el color según la condición isClicked.